# why and how the view is putted in the sidebar first block

Tags: views

I am studying the distrbution OpenAID 
http://drupal.org/project/openaid
---
I have a question:
in the block : **sidebar first**. there are some special view related with the url.

but in admin/struction/block. the sidebar first is none.

so question: why and how the view is putted in the sidebar first.

I get a clue : **Exposed form** , but more confuse is left.

Answer (score 0):

resolved it 
use **context module.**
Conditions select **view**
Reactions select **block - sidebar first**